# Google Sheets - Set range until the end of column & set each column is the sum of 3 columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I created a Google sheet containing 2 sheets(tabs).

The first sheet table is auto-created where it grabbing some data from my Google Ads.

The 2nd sheet table is where I manually created. Now,

1) I want the date row to auto-fill from the 1st sheet, but **how can I set the range from the first column until the end of the 1st sheet column**? Because now I set it to `=QUERY(Sheet1!B2:Sheet1!F2)`, but tomorrow Sheet 1 column gonna be until G, and I need to manually set the range to G2.

2) Under the Impression row, **I want each column to sum 3 columns from Sheet 1**. Meaning the first column formula gonna be `=SUM(Sheet1!B3:Sheet1!D3)`, the 2nd column gonna be `=SUM(Sheet1!E3:Sheet1!G3)` and so on until the end of Sheet 1 column. But what happens now is `=SUM(Sheet1!B3:Sheet1!D3)`, `=SUM(Sheet1!C3:Sheet1!E3)` and so on.

Here's an example https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BvG1inXgYfJxJ9mJf-TmkNxotleW3WqJIivzq0SNFk/edit?usp=sharing

Really hope some data analyst guru/sheet guru can give me some insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your `QUERY` formula on sheet2 use this in **B2** cell:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!B2:2)
```

instead of your `SUM` formula on sheet2 use this in **B3** cell and drag to the right:

```
=IF(LEN(B2), SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(3, COLUMN(), 4)&":"&
                                    ADDRESS(3, COLUMN()+2, 4))), )
```

[image: 0]

Comment: thank you for the 1st answer. But for the 2nd one, I don't think your formula works. The sum on the B3 is correct which are 56532 + 13055 + 7199. But at C2, the sum should be 5009 + 259 + 259, but instead it starts the sum from sheet1 column C.

Comment: no idea what you talking about. formula does exactly what you ask which is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpslB.png

Comment: in that case use: `=IF(LEN(B2), SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(3, COLUMN()^1.5, 4)&":"&ADDRESS(3, (COLUMN()^1.5)+2, 4))), )` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK1GN.png

Comment: great thank you! But, can you explain to me the real meaning behind the formula. I mean lets say for other sheet I want to make the sum to 7 instead of 3.. So what are the things that I need to change? And also how do you learn all this formula stuff, got any online cheat sheet?

Comment: for sum 7 you need to change `+2` to `+6` and instead of `COLUMN()^1.5` use: `ArrayFormula(IFERROR(QUERY(FILTER(ROW($A1:$A),NOT(MOD(ROW($A1:$A),7)))+2,"limit 1 offset "&COLUMN()-3),COLUMN()))`

Comment: nope, no cheat sheet... all I do is open sheet and test stuff until I crack it. without doing so I have no real knowledge